# jquery implementation with ajax

Tags: jquery

[image]

Why do I'm getting the result in the form of arrays in 7 and 10 whats needs to be done

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var myFacebookToken = '';

    function getFacebookInfo(){

        $.ajax('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token='+myFacebookToken,{

                success : function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    console.log(typeof(response));                      

                   $("#myProfileId").html('<a target="blank" href="https://facebook.com/'+response.id+'">https://facebook.com/'+response.id+'</a>');
                    $("#myName").text(response.name);
                    $("#myEmail").text(response.email);
                    $("#myGender").text(response.gender);
                    $("#myHometown").text(response.hometown.name);
                    $("#myStatus").text(response.relationship_status);
                    $("#myEducation").text(response.education);
                    $("#DOB").text(response.birthday);
                    $("#myLocation").text(response.location.name);
                    $("#myFav").text(response.favorite_athletes);

                    }

            }//end argument list 

        );// end ajax call

    }// end get facebook info

    $("#facebookBtn").on('click',getFacebookInfo)    
  });
```

That's my code any help would be appreciated.